# Upgrading version of org.eclipse.osgi jar

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, equinox

I'm trying to upgrade the OSGI framework jar from 3.8.1 to 3.10.1 but I'm facing some issues like some projects are available under 3.8.1 but not present under 3.10.1.

Examples : Projects such as org.eclipse.osgi.framework.adaptor & org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core are no longer available under 3.10.1 jar but are present in 3.8.1

My project is currently using 3.8.1 but when I'm trying to upgrade to org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.1 then it's showing the following error:

Unresolved bundle : org.eclipse.osgi.framework.adaptor.

What can be the workaround for this?

Comment: There are substantial changes between these versions. If your code is referencing those old packages it will need to be reworked.

Comment: are there any alternatives for these old packages in 3.10.1 or I need to go through there working in 3.8.1 and create my own classes to support this with 3.10.1?

Comment: My understanding is that there was a substantial rewrite so you will need to understand what was changed and how to deal with that. Note that classes with 'internal' in the package name are not part of the official API and you should never have been using them.